# Why do crawls work, but scope contains 0 items?

Tags: search, crawling, search-scope

We have got an interesting situation:

`http://intradev`

`http://mysites`

Our Intranet is based on SharePoint 2010 server small farm with 2 servers. AD is Windows 2003. The Search crawls both sites just fine.

I've even checked for 'success' crawls for `http://intradev` and subsites, and they're just fine.

In addition, people search works just fine. The People scope has over 300 items in it, while the 'All Sites' scope contains 0 items.

This causes the regular search to fail completely in the `http://Intradev`.

Any suggestions to what might be causing a situation like this?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this one?

Comment: Do you have exclusion rules that might remove them?  I did some inclusion rules at one point to get past this.

Comment: Are you saying here that the Central Admin search will not show scope items if using Claims Based?
I have a similar issue where the site collection scope shows 600 items, the central admin scope items is 0.
I'm thinking it is something to do with security to read the results.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is rather old, but I wanted to provide some insite to this as well.

If your Web Applications that you created in SP 2010 are "Claims Based" Web Apps, you will see this behavior.

Central Admin is not a CLAIMS Based Web App and cannot properly access the Items in the Scope for a CLaims Based Web App.

If you browse into the "Search Scopes" settings within the Site Collection > Site Settings, you should see the number of searhable items within the "All Sites" scope

Just wanted to put my 2 cents in..

Answer (score 2):

Are you using FAST Search?

The UI only really works for the standard SharePoint search. If you're looking at scopes on a FAST Search index they'll always be empty, and the scope rules won't be used (you've got to configure FAST scopes via Powershell, or code).

Answer (score 2):

This blog post provides an answer:
http://www.moss2007.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2010/03/18/sharepoint-search-scopes-approximate-item-count-is-incorrect.aspx

Apparently the behaviour is that it gets the number of items in a scope via a search query.  If for any reason that query fails (permissions, probably) you'll get a result of 0.

I had this problem but when I search on that scope from the front-end I get the results expected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile the 'All Sites' Scope?